# Embed images in Python documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, mkdocs

I have a python project that I want to create the documentation...

In this documentation, it is crucial allowing embedding images. Also, I would like to not create a separate file. In others words: the *.py file would contain both the script and the documentation (that has images embed).

Of course, later on this *.py would be processed by a tool to create a markdown or HTML report.

I took a look at [mkDocs](http://www.mkdocs.org/) and [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org), but I am not sure if they support these requirements.

Does anyone know how to do something similar with these tools (or another)?

Comment: What do you mean by "embed"? Encode image in Base64?

Comment: Just a link to the image file.  When the (html, md) file is opened in a browser, the browser should render the image

Comment: Then what do you mean by "I would like to not create a separate file"?

Comment: sorry for the confusion:   I am not familiar with all documentation tools.  In my mind, if I have a "source.py" , one common use case is to manually create a source.md file containing all the documentation. In this case, there will be two files.  What I want is source.py containing both the code and the documentation, image links and etc.  After running a external tool command, the source.md(html) would be generated

Comment: You can add documentation as docstrings in Python modules. With Sphinx, these docstrings can be extracted and included in the HTML output. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mzjn suggested, you can write docstrings in your python modules.  Docstrings may be valid reStructuredText.  reStructuredText syntax supports [inline images](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#images).  The given file name of the image must be either relative to the source file or absolute to the documentation root.  You must have a separate image file.

To build docs with Sphinx, you will need a set of reStructuredText files from which you build your documentation.  You can use [Sphinx `quick-start`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html) to generate the .rst source files.

Once you have written your docstrings, and have created .rst source files, and configured your `conf.py` to use the `autodoc` module to pull in your module's docstrings, then you can use Sphinx and its [`autodoc` module](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html) to build documentation in supported formats, including HTML.

Note that images must be in a supported format for the [builder](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/builders.html#builders)'s output.